# Why isn't my cube's velocity changing with rb.velocity = new Vector3(sidewaysForce, 0, 0) in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity so forgive me if I just did a stupid mistake. I am currently watching a tutorial from Brackeys, but I wanted to challenge myself by figuring out the movement myself. I got the moving forward correct, but I couldn't do the sideways movement. Since I've been spending a long time on the sideways movement, I just decided to watch the tutorial, but even when I used their code, it still didn't work. Can someone tell me why this isn't working? (FYI, in the code below, I did set all the public variables to some type of value).

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Sides : MonoBehaviour
{
    public KeyCode left;
    public KeyCode right;

    public float sidewaysForce;

    Rigidbody rb;
    Vector3 v3;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(left))
        {
            Debug.Log("Left");
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(-sidewaysForce, 0, 0);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(right))
        {
            Debug.Log("Right");
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(sidewaysForce, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try left and right between quotation marks:

```
    if (Input.GetKey("left"))
    {
        Debug.Log("Left");
        rb.velocity = new Vector3(-sidewaysForce, 0, 0);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey("right"))
    {
        Debug.Log("Right");
        rb.velocity = new Vector3(sidewaysForce, 0, 0);
    }
```

You can check how to get the different keys in:
InputManager is in: Edit -> ProjectSettings -> Input

Other option is to use `KeyCode`s, which I prefer instead of the string argument for the intellisense benefits:

```
  Update()
  {
  if ( Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow) )
    //move up
  if ( Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow) )
    //move down
  if ( Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow) )
    //move right
  if ( Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow) )
    //move left
  }
```

Comment: OP has `public KeyCode left;` and `public KeyCode right;` and configures those via the Inspector ... why should OP change this to the stringed version?

Comment: he should not. Just providing some proposals for the OP to try out, in case he might have missed setting something in the inspector or the input manager settings. However Its well pointed out for OP to check/show the `KeyCode` inspector config

Answer (score 0):

If you're not getting the logs you added in the console, then you may have forgotten either:

1. To set the values of variables `left` and `right` in the inspector.
2. To add the `Sides` component to your GameObject.

Comment: @Rasco the left and right variables are set to the A and D keys, and the script is in my object.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume your KeyCodes and the float are configured in the Inspector.

Either way you shouldn't do it like that!

You are completely overwriting the forward/backward movement and also the up/down movement with a hard `0` => you won't have any gravity and might break the forward movement - depending on which script is executed last.

You didn't share the forwards movement code so I can only guess but I suspect that there you do the very same thing like e.g.

```
rb.velocity = new Vector3(0, 0, someValue);
```

and therefore erase any sidewards movement from this script ;)

---

I would

- a) make sure to have all movement input related stuff in a single script. Everything else just makes it unnecessarily hard to maintain and debug
- b) make sure that your inputs don't eliminate each other

So something like e.g.

```
public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("References")]
    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody _rigidbody; 

    [Header("Config")]
    [SerializeField] private KeyCode _forward = KeyCode.W;
    [SerializeField] private KeyCode _backward = keyCode.S;

    [SerializeField] private KeyCode _left = KeyCode.A;
    [SerializeField] private KeyCode _right = KeyCode.D;

    public float speed; 

    private void Awake()
    {
        if(!_rigidbody) _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    private void FixedUpate()
    {
        // by default input is 0,0,0
        var input = Vector3.zero;

        // user input for forward
        if(Input.GetKey(_forward)) input.z = 1;
        else if(Input.GetKey(_backward)) input.z = -1;
        
        // user input for sidewards
        if(Input.GetKey(_left)) input.x = -1;
        else if(Input.GetKey(_right)) input.x = 1;

        // make sure both combined are not bigger then 1 (avoid faster diagonal movement)
        input = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(input, 1);

        // apply speed multiplier
        var velocity = input * speed;
        // preserve the Y velocity
        velocity.y = _rigidbody.velocity.y;

        // finally assign back to rigidbody
        _rigidbody.velocity = velocity;
    }
}
```

---

In general though way more flexible and without having to configure and check the KeyCodes manually you could rather use [`Input.GetAxis`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxis.html) and do e.g.

```
public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("References")]
    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody _rigidbody; 

    [Header("Config")]
    public float speed; 

    private void Awake()
    {
        if(!_rigidbody) _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    private void FixedUpate()
    {
        var input = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));

        // make sure both combined are not bigger then 1 (avoid faster diagonal movement)
        input = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(input, 1);

        // apply speed multiplier
        var velocity = input * speed;
        // preserve the Y velocity for the gravity
        velocity.y = _rigidbody.velocity.y;

        // finally assign back to the rigidbody
        _rigidbody.velocity = velocity;
    }
}
```

You can configure the mappings in <kbd>Edit</kbd> → <kbd>Project Settings</kbd> → <kbd>Input Manager</kbd> but by default the

- `Horizontal` already refers to both `A`/`D` as well as `LeftArrow`/`RightArrow`
- `Vertical` already refers to both `W`/`S` as well as `UpArrow`/`DownArrow`

[image]

and additionally `GetAxis` slightly interpolates the input so it doesn't immediately jump from `0` to `1` and back but rather increases and decreases smoothly over some frames.

If the latter bothers you you can also use [`GetAxisRaw`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxisRaw.html) which does not do the smoothing.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that I did in fact made a stupid mistake. In my other script that makes the player move forward, it sets the velocity to (0, 0, 100) in the FixedUpdate() which meant that the x axis doesn't change. Sorry for wasting your time.